# Integrating Cordova / Phonegap with Sencha Architect

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

Currently in my `Sencha touch` app, i connect to an external server to fetch records from a database. Then, I display these records on my view.

Now, i want to fetch data from an external server and save it in a local database (in the phone it self). I found out that i should use `phonegap` (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) to make this possible.

Can someone point me to a tutorial or tell me how to integrate `phonegap` with `Sencha Architect` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is integrate Sencha Touch with PhoneGap. Below video is a good starting point. It goes through the process of creating a Sencha Touch application and adding PhoneGap (and also Cordova) support to it. It also shows how you can build your application for iOS and Android platforms.

https://vimeo.com/76568053